# Getting DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted for multilevel/complex object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, lombok

I have a complex object `Test` in the entity class `Item`.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum TestStatus {
    TO_RUN("To Run"),
    RUNNING("Running"),
    PASSED("Passed"),
    FAILED("Failed");

    public static TestStatus fromValue(String value) {
        //...implementation
    }

    private final String value;
}

@Data
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@DynamoDBFlattened(attributes = {
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "test.task.id", mappedBy = "id"),
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "test.task.status", mappedBy = "status")
})
public class TestTask {
    private String id;
    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
    private TestStatus status;
}

@Data
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@DynamoDBFlattened(attributes = {
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "test.suite.name", mappedBy = "name"),
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "test.suite.version", mappedBy = "version")
})
public class TestSuite {
    private String name;
    private String version;
}

@Data
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Test {
    private TestSuite suite;
    private TestTask task;
}

@Data
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "com.example.item")
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private Test test; // This is a complex object as structure given above.
}

On the call of dynamoDBMapper.save(item); getting exception.

@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DynamoDBItemRepository implements ItemRepository {
    //...
    @Override
    public Item save(Item item) {
        dynamoDBMapper.save(item); // Getting DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted
        return item;
    }
    //...
}
```

I am getting the exception

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$Rules$NotSupported.set(StandardModelFactories.java:664) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.578.jar:?]
```

What am I missing? Please help!

Comment: were u able to resolve it?

Comment: Nope, I had to simplify the object.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the code.

I tried to reproduce the error, but found the first problem: no hash key specified.
so I used `Item.name` as the hash key in order to go further on the test.

The second problem matched your description

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted
```

Found out that you missed an annotation `@DynamoDBDocument`, which should be added to the class `Test` since it is a nested type:

```
...
@DynamoDBDocument
...
public class Test {
```

see document [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBDocument)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to migrate to [AWS SDK for Java 2.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/#using-the-sdk) where you can use complex objects: [doc](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/tree/master/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced#using-inheritance)